# How to save full Vowpal Wabbit python model (pyvw)?

Tags: save, vowpalwabbit

I tried saving a Vowpal Wabbit model using `model.save(<filepath>)`. But when I reload the model (using the `-i <filepath>` flag), model hyperparameters such as `power_t` and `initial_t` aren't the same (they get reinitialized). The saved file also seems to me a bit smaller in size that it should (not sure if it's compressed).

This is counter intuitive: why doesn't the `.save()` method save the full model? And are there alternative save methods to save the FULL model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`power_t` and `initial_t` are only relevant for training. When just doing predictions they are not needed. By default when saving a model VW assumes it will be used for prediction only when loaded. If you intend to continue training from the loaded model then when you initialize VW you need to specify `--save_resume` so that the extra state is stored in the model. This includes `power_t` and `initial_t` (which is saved into a different variable t).

Comment: Thanks. This allowed me to be able to continue with training from a saved model (saved using ```model.save(<filepath>)``` with a non-zero ```power_t``` and with the ```adaptive```, ```normalized```, and ```invariant``` flags set. However, when I set ```--passes x``` with x > 1, it produces different results (learns different weights)

Comment: When say it learns different weights, do you mean compared to not adding `--passes`? This is expected as using multiple passes, means the data is being trained on multiple times. Making multiple passes over the data will certainly cause different weights to be learned.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I meant. I'm running the following test: I instantiate a VW model with ```--passes 3 --save_resume```. I train the model. Then I save and load the model within the same session (I should now have two identical models) using ```--i <filepath> --save_resume --passes 3```. I further train both models on another dataset (different from the first training dataset). At this point I expect that both models produce the same predictions on a test set, but they don't. They DO produce identical predictions if I run this test without ```--passes```, however.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure what the notion of ```passes``` really means in pyvw, since I train the model sample by sample in a for loop. I just asked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61373881/6382242).

Comment: Yeah so depending on how you invoke things passes may or may not affect things in pyvw. It's one of the parameters that is tricky in this way. I would think the predictions should be identical in that case. Can you please create an issue with the script you're running and the data you are using and I can look into it further?