# What does --passes do in Python VowpalWabbit?

Tags: model, training-data, vowpalwabbit

The --passes flag is the number of training passes. But it's unclear what the notion of passes means when training a Python VW model, within a for loop for example.

e.g. If I'm training a model example by example within a for-loop like this:

```
for line in train:
    model.learn(line)
```

How could there be multiple passes if each training sample is learned from only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python the `passes` option only affect when the inbuilt driver is used. This only occurs when a data file and or passes is specified in the configuration for the VW object. It does not cause different behavior for `model.learn(line)`.

This is the check (internally to the Python code) for running the inbuilt parser:

```py
class vw(pylibvw.vw):
    def __init__(self, arg_str=None, **kw):
        # ...
        ext_file_args = ['d', 'data', 'passes']
        if any(x in kw for x in ext_file_args):
            pylibvw.vw.run_parser(self)
```

This is one of those confusing cases caused by the fact VW was as a command line tool first. This is definitely something it would be good to make clearer as we work on the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

`vw = pyvw.vw("-d train.txt --cb_explore_adf --passes 2 --cache --cb_type ips -p train_predictions.txt -f vw.model")`